# How to center image links within a container?

Tags: html, css

I want to understand why images don't necessarily center properly. I was told that by default, `<a>` tags are `inline` elements, so in order to change their size, you will need to change their `display` property to `block` or `inline block`. Then, once you set the width of the `<a>` tag, you can set the width of the `<img>` tag to 100% and it will conform to the shape of the `<a>` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Photo Gallery</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/lightbox/lightbox.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=container>

            <!-- <form action="form-field"> -->
            <input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Search(16pt)">
            <!-- </form> -->

            <div class="images">
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-3"><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" data-lightbox="image-4"><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" data-lightbox="image-5"><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" data-lightbox="image-6"><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" data-lightbox="image-7"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" data-lightbox="image-8"><img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Image 8"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" data-lightbox="image-9"><img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Image 9"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" data-lightbox="image-10"><img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" data-lightbox="image-11"><img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></a>
                <a href= "photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" data-lightbox="image-12"><img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="search"] {
    height: 30px;
}

.images {
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

/* If a flex container is set to width */
```

But I've tried that it still hasn't been working. I know images have their own dimensions when they get imported, but whats the logic here? I keep having to expierment with CSS settings when working with images because they are so unpredictable.

https://ibb.co/Y02j6VL

Comment: why aren't there " " by your container class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be 4 possibilities.

**1)** Change your *.images* padding to margin: 0 auto, like so:

```
.images {
  border: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**2)** Depending on your layout its also possible that images is taking 100% width.
So you need to also add `text-align:center` on *images* div.

**3)** Your images div can be tranformed to `display:flex` and then set `justify-content: center` on it.

**4)** If you want to use *.container* content to be centered. You can use `align-item:center` on the images div. Since, container has `flex-direction:column`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 30px;
}

.images {
  border: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="images">
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"><img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-3"><img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" data-lightbox="image-4"><img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" data-lightbox="image-5"><img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" data-lightbox="image-6"><img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
    <a href="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" data-lightbox="image-7"><img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh I just realized something, the text-align property works on images because text characters in a sense are inline, similar to images, correct?

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha You are right in  a way. By default anchor tags have display:inline. SO they are treated like text.
Consider upvoting if this helps you. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is using `display: flex;` here is a solution that continues to use it. However it makes more sense to `flex` the `images class`. To center the content use `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` depending on `flex-direction`.

Sidenote: `padding: 0 auto;` is not a thing, there is no `auto` value for `padding`.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;

}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 30px;
}

.images {
  width: 245px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px red solid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/lightbox/lightbox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class=container>

        <!-- <form action="form-field"> -->
        <input type="search" id="site-search" placeholder="Search(16pt)">
        <!-- </form> -->

        <div class="images">
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Image 1"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```